# Download program into AVR chip with FTDI4232

Tags: avr, ftdi

### **Background info**

1. WinAVR:
   I installed WinAVR, and use avrdude.exe comes with WinAVR to download program into our board.
2. Adapter card:
   We have an adapter card with FTDI4232 and AVR m328p on it. PC connects to FTDI4232 with a micro USB cable.
3. Schematic:
   Sorry, I cannot post pics. So just describe the major part of schematic here. Two wires from(DATA_P & DATA_N pins) out from macro USB connector to DP[pin8] and DM[pin7] on 4232. And four wires(SCK, MOSI, MISO, SS_N) out from 4232 to m328p.
4. How to download program into the card before: Via pocket programmer. But we cannot give one pocket programmer to every engineer, so try to find out a way to download the program into m328p. Coz we have already had FTDI4232 on board, so this seems to be the best choice.

### **Can I download program via FTDI4232 on adapter card?**

1. I know there is dedicated programmer based on 4232 chip, but this is our own design, I am not sure we can do it or not according to the above schematic.

### **what I did**

1. Run this command:
   C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.exe -c 4232h -p m328p -U flash:w:\Desktop\work\a_card\WinAVR\blink\blink.hex:i
   But got the following error:
   avrdude.exe: Error: no libftdi or libusb support. Install libftdi1/libusb-1.0 or  libftdi/libusb and run configure/make again.
2. Then, download the compiled libftdi package from this link:
   https://code.google.com/p/picusb/downloads/detail?name=libftdi1-1.0_devkit_mingw32_17Feb2013.zip
   , and extract it as “compiled_libftdi”.
3. There is not too much info about how to use this compiled package, so I just found info online.
   (1) I installed WinUSB driver for the first two ports of 4232 by Zadig. I can choose one port in the drop down menu, then choose “WinUSB(v6.1,7600…)”, “Install WCID Driver”.
   (2) Then, enter into the “compiled_libftdi” folder, run “find_all”, I saw:
   Number of FTDI devices found:1
   Checking device: 0
   Manufactureer: FTDI, Description: USB <-> Serial Converter
   I think it means the USB driver for libftdi package installed successfully.
4. Run the above download command again, still failed.
5. I thought maybe because the avrdude.exe is out of date. So download a .exe from here:
   http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/avrdude-6.0.1-mingw32.zip
   And replace the old one in the WinAVR folder.
6. Still got the error, but got one extra line info:
   avrdude.exe: programmer operation not supported

Comment: What is the error code or message exactly?

Comment: The error code is:
avrdude.exe: Error: no libftdi or libusb support. Install libftdi1/libusb-1.0 or libftdi/libusb and run configure/make again.

Comment: And currently, this error got solved. I googled some relative info, and found that I need a compiled avrdude with libftdi inside. 
This is the page talking about this issue:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avrdude-61-released
And this is the page to download the compiled avrdude with ftdi programming supported:
http://helix.air.net.au/index.php/avrdude-and-ftdi-232h/
After download the .exe and .conf, just replace these two inside the winavr folder, and install the libusb-win32, avrdude.exe can detect 4232 chip.

Comment: The next issue is when I run:
>avrdude.exe -c 4232h -p m328p
I got the following error:
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
             this check.

This means the connection got something wrong.

Comment: I suspect the FTDI chip working mode is set incorrectly, or the avrdude.conf is not setup correctly. Can anybody helps me out?

Comment: did you solve your problem? please tell me the solution. I have the same problem